# Calling ExecNotificationQueryAsync() again from within interface Indicate() callback?

Tags: c++, windows, com, wmi

I'm using WMI to track a process creation chain (process 1.exe creates process 2.exe, 2.exe creates 3.exe etc). Everything works fine, except that when one process is created I'm trying to issue another ExecNotificationQueryAsync() from within the interface Indicate() method which gets triggered, with the query

```
SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process' AND TargetInstance.ParentProcessId = 1234
```

where parent process ID is set to the PID of the process that caused this call (Win32_Process.ProcessId), not before I call CancelAsyncCall() for the current query. The syntax of the query is ok as it works fine first time but Indicate() isn't called anymore as soon as I issue the ExecNotificationQueryAsync() with the new parent PID, although the process is being created.

What am I doing wrong?